# How to increase privvmpages size in Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, vps

**Is it possible to increase privvmpages size in Ubuntu VPS server ?**

I can see 5GB allocated to privvmpages when I execute below command. Is it possible to upgrade this value if I am using VPS ? I know that I can change all kernel values in dedicated server. But is it possible in VPS?

```
sudo cat /proc/user_beancounters


resource                     held              maxheld              barrier                limit              failcnt    

kmemsize                 58073035             77520896            202133143            222346456                    0
lockedpages                     0                   16                 2670                 2670                    0
privvmpages               3751751              5235086              5242880              5242880                   84
shmpages                    15451                18213               327680               327680                    0
dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
numproc                       675                 1368                 1600                 1600                    0
physpages                 1226466              1590840              5242880              5242880                    0
vmguarpages                     0                    0              2621440           2147483647                    0
oomguarpages              1347050              1697589              2621440           2147483647                    0
numtcpsock                    205                 1609                 3000                 3000                    0
numflock                       49                   60                 2000                 2000                    0
numpty                          4                    9                  512                  512                    0
numsiginfo                      1                   54                 1024                 1024                    0
tcpsndbuf                 1293240              9589104              9582922             13674826                 3141
tcprcvbuf                 1200984              8442256              9582922             13674826                    0
othersockbuf               159512               205144              3194307              5922243                    0
dgramrcvbuf                     0               444328              3194307              3194307                    0
numothersock                  142                  155                 3000                 3000                    0
dcachesize                9460918              9461760              8515584              9461760                    0
numfile                      7620                14045                30000                30000                    0
dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
numiptent                      50                   50                  384                  384                    0
```

Comment: Do you have access to the underlying hypervisor ?

Comment: I don't have the access...In VPS, it's restricted by the provider right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have access to the underlying hypervisor then you as the user of a container (VM) cannot change that value.

Comment: could you let me know how to change the value If at all I have the access ??

Comment: I have no idea but I would read the openvz documentation to find out.